# How to Open a link from a VF page in a new window

Tags: visualforce

I have the following code in my SLDS VF page:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!result != null}"><a href='/{!acct.id}'>{!acct.Salesforce_Account_ID__c} <br/></a></apex:outputText>
```

Although the link is showing as expected, when clicked, the current page is being overwritten with the new one. I do have the options to right click and open in new Window/Tab, but is there a way to open the link in new window with left click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm)

```
<apex:outputlink 
    rendered="{!result != null}" 
    value="/{!acct.id}"
    target="_blank"
>{!acct.Salesforce_Account_ID__c}</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: or ... `value={!URLFOR($Action.Account.View,acct.Id)}"` for the purist

Comment: @cropredy, purist and more safer, dynamic which works even when a page is used in community with a sub domain..